# Windows 7 x64 install

Tags: windows-7, windows, 64-bit

I have an older computer that is currently running on window 7 x86. this has worked fine for me until i tried to play newer games that require 64 bit. I want to upgrade but my cd drive is broken and the only flash drive I have is a 128 gb that can't be formatted because it has too much volume. Before I go and buy a new one are there any other choices I have to install windows 7 x64?

Comment: Your question is not clear.  You simply need to install the 64-bit installation, what options you select, are the same options you selected when you installed the 32-bit installation.

Comment: "the only flash drive I have is a 128 gb that can't be formatted because it has too much volume" - What does "too much volume" mean? You mean there's important data on it? Or you are unable to format it for some reason? If the latter try using [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie) to create a Win7 USB installer.

Comment: I am unable to download and install windows 7 x64 because my cd drive is broken. i am unable to use a usb flash drive because whenever I try to format it, it tells me the device cannot be formatted because it has too much volume or something like that. Are there any options before i just buy a new USB Flash Drive?

Comment: I might also like to add that the USB Flash Drive is  a usb 3.0 Could that be causing the problem???

Comment: Windows can format USB 3.0 drives just fine. Did you try using the program I suggested above? If that fails too then let us know the exact error message and not something vague.

Comment: IIRC there's a question/answer on doing an install entirely without a dvd somewhere

Comment: How should i set up this flash drive to install 64bit?

Comment: You state "I have an **older** computer that is currently running on window 7 x86." Is the computer 64-bit?

Comment: No It is not. But I think Karan Helped me figure it out. and for that I thank you karan. :)

Comment: nope. Thought I had it. I had The usb drive plugged in and restarted my computer. when it restarted it booted right up on the same 32 bit.

Comment: What do you mean by "No It is not"? If the CPU isn't 64-bit then you can't install 64-bit Windows.

Answer (score 2):

First up, make sure that your processor is 64-bit. You can figure that out with [Speccy](https://www.piriform.com/speccy/download/standard) and/or Google. (If your machine isn't 64-bit, you'll never be able to run a 64-bit OS.)

Go to the [Microsoft Software Recovery](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-recovery) page. Enter your 64-bit Windows 7 product key and fill out any other forms it throws at you. It'll download an ISO file, which is the image of the installer disc.

Download [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html) or [WinRar](http://www.win-rar.com/start.html?&L=0). Extract the ISO into a new folder. You'll find a file called `setup.exe` there. Run that - it's the standard Windows 7 installer. Follow the prompts and you're good to go.

Comment: Just a note that the Software Recovery page won't work for OEM users.